# expected LP_c_ubyte instance instead of memoryview

Tags: python, opencv, ctypes

When I send the image data to c function, there is a error appear

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_ubyte instance instead of memoryview
```

I know there is a type error.

This is the c++ function define:

```
int cv_face_detect (
    ...
    const unsigned char *image,
    ...
)
```

and with c++, I notice c++ send image data with cv package

```
using namespace cv;

Mat m_image_mat;
m_image_mat = imread ( full_file_name );

cv_face_detect(..., m_image_mat.data, ...);
```

In python, I set the  argtypes, and send image data with vc2

```
cv_face_detect.argtypes = (..., POINTER(c_ubyte), ...)

img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
cv_face_detect(..., img.data, ...)
```

then, the error appeared

I wan't to know how to convert memoryview to const unsigned char * data, that I can send image data to c function

thanks

Comment: There may be a more direct route from whatever the `memoryview` references, rather than using the view.

Comment: @eryksun thanks, I use cvmat = cv.fromarray(img), that I get the cvmat object, I think it's similar as C++ cv::Mat data attribute, but cvmat don't has data attribute...